# How do I prevent program from terminating when user inputs a string when the program expects an integer?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, do-while

I'm trying to set up a do-while loop that will re-prompt the user for input until they enter an integer greater than zero. I cannot use try-catch for this; it's just not allowed. Here's what I've got:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;
do{
System.out.println("Enter a number (int): ");
num = scnr.nextInt();
} while(num<0 || !scnr.hasNextLine());
```

It'll loop if a negative number is inputted, but if a letter is, the program terminates.

Comment: Have either of our answers helped you?

Comment: This is for an introductory class project (hence why I can't use try-catch--because we haven't learned it), and I don't know if we're allowed to use parseInt().
It makes sense to me, and I'm going to try to implement it now. Thanks, guys.

Comment: If you can't use try-catch and you can't use string regex/parseInt then you're doing a ridiculous project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take it in as a string, and then use regex to test if the string contains only numbers. So, only assign `num` the integer value of the string if it is in fact an integer number. That means you need to initialize `num` to `-1` so that if it is not an integer, the while condition will be true and it will start over.

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = -1;
String s;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number (int): ");
    s = scnr.next().trim(); // trim so that numbers with whitespace are valid

    if (s.matches("\\d+")) { // if the string contains only numbers 0-9
        num = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
} while(num < 0 || !scnr.hasNextLine());
```

---

Sample run:

```
Enter a number (int): 
-5
Enter a number (int): 
fdshgdf
Enter a number (int): 
5.5
Enter a number (int): 
5
```

Answer (score 3):

As using try-catch is not allowed, call `nextLine()` instead
of `nextInt()`, and then test yourself if the `String` you got
back is an integer or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test038 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = -1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number (int): ");
            String str = scnr.nextLine().trim();
            if (str.matches("\\d+")) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(str);
                break;
            }

        } while (num < 0 || !scnr.hasNextLine());
        System.out.println("You entered: " + num);
    }

}
```